# prove linear independence of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f_1,...,f_k$ be polynomials at field $K$ not including the zero polynomial and $\deg f_i \neq \deg f_j$ for every $i \neq j$ Show that polynomials $f_1,...,f_k $ are linear independent.

I don't know how to use the information that $\deg f_i \neq \deg f_j$.

I will try to consider a linear combination $a_1f_1+...+a_kf_k=0$ and show that then $a_1=...=a_k=0$ but I don't know how do derive it.

Comment: Here's a hint: Suppose $a_1f_1 + \cdots + a_kf_k = 0$. Since all the polynomials have different degrees, there must be a polynomial $f_j$ whose degree is the largest. What do you know about $a_j$?

Comment: Ok I know that $f_j$ doesn't belong to $span{(f_1,..,f_{j-1},f_{j+1},...,f_k)}$ so then $a_j=0$ ?

Comment: Prove that the $f_i$ with largest degree can't be a linear combination of the others.  Then prove that the $f_j$ with next highest degree can't be a linear combination of the others minus the first.  And so on.

Comment: @tom Yes.  If you don't see why, assume the contrary, move all other $f_i$'s to the other side and see the contradiction.

Comment: OK I see why $f_j$ isn't linear comb.of the rest and so on but as I show it can I assume respectively that $a_j$ and so on are $0$ ?

Comment: Let's assume that $f_1$ is not a linear combination of the set of $\{f_2, f_3, \dots, f_k\}$.  Then $f_1$ cannot be written as $a_2f_2 + a_3f_3 + \cdots a_kf_k$ for ANY combination of $a_i$'s.  Now let's look at the equation $c_1f_1+c_2f_2+\cdots c_kf_k=0$.  Subtract all of the terms but the first from both sides to get : $c_1f_1 = -c_2f_2 - \cdots -c_kf_k$.  If $c_1\ne 0$, then we can divide it on both sides.  We'd then have $f_1 = \frac {-c_2}{c_1}f_2 - \cdots -\frac{c_k}{c_1}f_k$.  Thus $f_1$ would be a linear combination of the other functions. A contradiction.

Comment: ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that  $f_1 ,f_2 ,...,f_k$ are linear dependent and let $f_j $ be the polynomial whose degree is the largest then $f_j = c_1f_1+ ...c_{j-1}f_{j-1} + c_{j+1}f_{j+1}+.... +c_{k}f_{k}$ but the degree of right hand side is less thar left hand side and this is contradiction